# Python KIVY module how to change positions of buttons, labels etc freely using x axis and y axis instead of grids

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently learning KIVY in Python and trying to figure out how to freely choose position of an element such as label and buttons, like in Tkinter you can use relx and rely to choose excact position. Do anyone know if that is possible in KIVY?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `pos` and `size` to what you want. If the parent is something like a FloatLayout, also set the `size_hint` to `None, None` to avoid the layout automatically resizing it.